# can we store browser name in Case object from Self service portal

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-portal

when we log case from self service portal ,I want to store the browser name which I am using to log case on that case record. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, like this:

```
<apex:page id="CaptureBrowser" standardController="Case">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField id="browserId" value="{!Case.Description}" />
                <script>
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.browserId}').value = navigator.userAgent;
                </script>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

All I'm doing is giving the input field an id, then accessing it via the $Component global value, and using Javascript to put the navigator value in there.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I want the same for standard page of salesforce like self service portal.